# How to remove duplicate rows in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I want to remove duplicate rows from the following query can someone please assist

```
SELECT 
   OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
   item_description DESCRIPTION,
   item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
   FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM 
   OM_ITEM_MASTER, FM_PRICE_LIST
ORDER BY 
   item_description
```

Comment: You need to add a join condition between the two tables.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What are `duplicate rows` for you, please add some samples and result.

Comment: I have run this querry  SELECT  OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
       item_description DESCRIPTION,
       item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
       FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER inner join FM_PRICE_LIST on
 OM_ITEM_MASTER.[PART_NO] = FM_PRICE_LIST.[PART_NO]  --<-- Criteria 
ORDER BY ITEM_MANUFACTURER but i end up with the following result  which is only a single row NT321 NULL NULL 87665

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are getting a cartesian product of these two tables, every row in  `OM_ITEM_MASTE` gets matched to with every row in `FM_PRICE_LIST`, which is almost never the case (except if you are creating some test data).

You need to define a condition to tell sql server explicitly that how rows in one table are related to rows in other table.

```
SELECT OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
       item_description DESCRIPTION,
       item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
       FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER,
     FM_PRICE_LIST
WHERE M_ITEM_MASTER.[ColumnName] = FM_PRICE_LIST.[ReferrencingColumn]  --<-- Criteria 
ORDER BY item_description
```

Or even better you should use the proper join syntax something like this...

```
SELECT OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
       item_description DESCRIPTION,
       item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
       FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER INNER JOIN  FM_PRICE_LIST
  ON M_ITEM_MASTER.[ColumnName] = FM_PRICE_LIST.[ReferrencingColumn]
ORDER BY item_description
```

Comment: hy ave tried the query SELECT distinct OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
       item_description DESCRIPTION,
       item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
       FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER,
     FM_PRICE_LIST
WHERE OM_ITEM_MASTER.[PART_NO] = FM_PRICE_LIST.[PART_NO]  --<-- Criteria 
ORDER BY item_description  but instead it only displays 1 row which is NT321 NULL NULL 87665

Answer (score 0):

Add a `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT` clause.

To reduce the number of rows in the set use a `JOIN` between the two tables with an `ON`.